# Unable to Show Data insde dojox.grid.DataGrid with dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore

Tags: dojo

I am using DOJO ItemFileReadStore with dojox.grid.DataGrid to show Data Inside a Grid

Please see the Image here 
http://imageshare.web.id/viewer.php?file=kdfvrkmn6k7xafmi4jdy.jpg

**EMployee.Java**

```
public class Employee {

    String name;
    String dept;
// Setters and Getters
}
```

**This is My Servlet**

```
response.setContentType("text/x-json;charset=UTF-8");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
List list = new ArrayList();
Employee emp1 = new Employee();
Employee emp2 = new Employee();
emp1.setDept("CSE");
emp1.setName("Vamsi");
emp2.setDept("EEE");
emp2.setName("Raju");
list.add(emp1);
list.add(emp2);
List jsonresponse = new ArrayList();
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
JSONObject nextObject = new JSONObject();
nextObject.put("name", list.get(i));
jsonresponse.add(nextObject);
}
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("label", "name");
json.put("items", jsonresponse.toArray());
response.getWriter().write(json.toString());
}
```

**This is MY JSP Page**

```
<body class=" claro ">
<span dojoType="dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore" jsId="store1" url="http://localhost:8080/Man/MyServlet2"></span>

<table dojoType="dojox.grid.DataGrid" store="store1" 
   style="width: 100%; height: 500px;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="150px" field="name">Name</th>
            <th width="150px" field="dept">Dept</th>
                    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

**Please see the Image here 
http://imageshare.web.id/viewer.php?file=kdfvrkmn6k7xafmi4jdy.jpg**

Please help , Thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+1 for posting the server output (firebug screenshot) in your question. This makes a lot easier for people to help you - for example I can easily see that the data format is still not quite right. You are getting better at both dojo and stackoverflow, it seems!

Remember that the ItemFileReadStore expects the data to be in a particular format. Your servlet is producing:

```
{label: "name", items: [
    {name: {dept: "CSE", name: "Vansi"}}, 
    {name: {dept: "ABC", name: "Abcd"}}
]}
```

You see you are telling the store that each item's "name" is an object with some properties ("dept" and "name"). This is why the grid shows `object Object` in the name column. It should be:

```
{label: "name", items: [
    {dept: "CSE", name: "Vansi"}, 
    {dept: "ABC", name: "Abcd"}
]}
```

I'm not very good with java, but I believe only a small change in your servlet is required:

```
// The for loop that adds employees to jsonresponse.
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) 
{
    // Instead of adding the 
    Emloyee e = (Employee)list.get(i);
    JSONObject nextObject = new JSONObject();
    nextObject.put("name", e.getName());
    nextObject.put("dept", e.getDept());
    jsonresponse.add(nextObject);
}
```

In fact, it's possible that you can just do `json.put("items", list.toArray());` instead of adding each employee to `jsonresponse`.

Comment: Thank you my friend , just json.put("items", list.toArray()); has been sufficient nd its working fine .